# AWS Java SDK from Groovy Script - Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, groovy

I'm using the AWS Java S3 SDK with the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.155</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works great from Java:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard()
   .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
   .withRegion(region)
   .build();
```

If I try and do the exact thing through a Groovy Script:

```
def credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, secret);
def s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
   .standard()
   .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
   .withRegion(s3region)
   .build()
```

I get an exception:

```
Caught: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: 
Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
```

Explicitly adding the stax dependency to my .pom starts to give me conflicting classes elsewhere.

Is there some trick to this with Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding stax-api:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab('stax:stax:1.2.0')
@GrabExclude('stax:stax-api')
```

Pulling in just stax was giving me:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/tools/RootLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
```

The stax-api dependency has a javax.xml.namespace.QName class that conflicts with the one provided by the JRE (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html).